# Do programs source .bashrc when run?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, path

I append to my `PATH` environment variable in my `.bashrc` file (Ubuntu v12). I also have a service (Atlassian Bamboo) that relies on the modifications to `PATH`. When I restart the service (which runs as my local user where the `.bashrc` changes are made), will it "source" the `.bashrc` file to freshen up the environment variables so it has them? Or do I need to reboot the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-interactive shells don't source `.bashrc` unless manually requested, and moreover, the service likely doesn't invoke shell (unless it has some kind of wrapper script).

How to proceed depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve. Services usually have their own config files to modify their behaviour, and environment can also be specified for each service specifically (I'm not an Ubuntu user, so I'm not sure how this works on your system - it's upstart, right?). You can also modify `.profile` which is loaded at login - variables, exported in this file, are accessible to all children. If the service is actually run globally by the init system (by root that just switches to your username), this won't work either. `/etc/environment` may work, but I wouldn't recommend that, it's ugly.

In your case, the only really clean way is to set the environment for your service.

Answer (score 0):

For non-interactive bash shells, such as bash scripts, the `.bashrc` file is *not* sourced. Only interactive bash shells that are not login shells source this file. For more information, you can look at the INVOCATION section of the bash(1) man page.

A service typically won't be a descendant of an interactive shell anyway, so that the `.bashrc` changes won't have any effect on it.